# How to filter JSON data?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(
    'https://www.off---white.com/en/GB/men/products/omia066s188000161001.json')
print(r.text)
```

The code above reruns the following:

```
{"available_sizes":[{"id":104792,"name":"40","preorder_only":false},
                    {"id":104794,"name":"42","preorder_only":false},
                    {"id":104795,"name":"43","preorder_only":false}]}
```

How would I filter the above data so then when I specify the name value of 40, the `id` value of 104792 is printed?

In simple terms if I ask for the value of 'name' 40 then the script will print the 'id' value.

Comment: Filter it in what sense? You question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method [`.json()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) of [`requests.Reponse`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response).

```
data = r.json()
try:
    value = next(size['id'] 
                 for size in data['available_sizes'] 
                 if size['name'] == '40')
except StopIteration:
    value = None
```

In `value` will be stored first size id with `name == '40'` if such exist, if not `None`.

Comment: Worked a treat - thank you very much :) Will mark as answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = foo["available_sizes"]
new_dict = {}
for dict_ in data:
    new_dict.update({dict_["name"]: dict["id"]})
```